# R - Getting values from other columns when conditions are met

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data table something like this.

```
Firm Year Moveyear Address OriginAddress DestinationAddress
  A  2000                     
  A  2001 2001              15Grand_Ave     700Grand_Ave
  A  2002
  A  2003 2003              700Grand_Ave    20Washington_Ave
  A  2004
  B  2000
  B  2001 
  B  2002 2002              2730State_st    40Washington_Ave
  B  2003
  B  2004
  C
  .
  .
```

It is a panel dataset showing relocation information of each firm for multiple years. I want to add (or assign) address information to '*Address*' column by using '*OriginAddress*' and '*DestinationAddress*' columns.

For example, 15Grand_Ave should be assigned to Firm A's Address column in 2000 since it was the original address before the firm moves to 700Grand_Ave in 2001. And 700Grand_Ave should be assigned to Firm A's Address column in 2001 and 2002 since it was its address before it moves to 20Washington_Ave in 2003.

**So the result that I want :**

```
Firm Year Moveyear  Address        OriginAddress DestinationAddress
  A  2000         15Grand_Ave            
  A  2001 2001    700Grand_Ave      15Grand_Ave     700Grand_Ave
  A  2002         700Grand_Ave
  A  2003 2003    20Washington_Ave  700Grand_Ave    20Washington_Ave
  A  2004         20Washington_Ave
  B  2000         2730State_st
  B  2001         2730State_st
  B  2002 2002    40Washington_Ave  2730State_st    40Washington_Ave
  B  2003         40Washington_Ave
  B  2004         40Washington_Ave
  C
  .
  .
```

I am guessing I need to use for-loop and ifelse statement in R but I am having trouble with coding. Please share any ideas with me.

Comment: Hi Chicago2017 please call the `dput` function on your data.frame/data.table and copy and paste the output from the console into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Replace blanks with NA
  na_if('') %>%
  #Arrange data by Firm and Year 
  arrange(Firm, Year) %>%
  #Copy destination address to Address
  mutate(Address = DestinationAddress) %>%
  #For each Firm
  group_by(Firm) %>%
  #Fill NA values with previous non-NA values
  tidyr::fill(Address) %>%
  #Replace NA with first non-NA value in OriginAddress
  mutate(Address = replace(Address,is.na(Address),first(na.omit(OriginAddress))))


#  Firm   Year Moveyear Address          OriginAddress DestinationAddress
#   <chr> <int>    <int> <chr>            <chr>         <chr>             
# 1 A      2000       NA 15Grand_Ave      NA            NA                
# 2 A      2001     2001 700Grand_Ave     15Grand_Ave   700Grand_Ave      
# 3 A      2002       NA 700Grand_Ave     NA            NA                
# 4 A      2003     2003 20Washington_Ave 700Grand_Ave  20Washington_Ave  
# 5 A      2004       NA 20Washington_Ave NA            NA                
# 6 B      2000       NA 2730State_st     NA            NA                
# 7 B      2001       NA 2730State_st     NA            NA                
# 8 B      2002     2002 40Washington_Ave 2730State_st  40Washington_Ave  
# 9 B      2003       NA 40Washington_Ave NA            NA                
#10 B      2004       NA 40Washington_Ave NA            NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Firm = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L), Moveyear = c(NA, 2001L, NA, 2003L, 
NA, NA, NA, 2002L, NA, NA), Address = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), OriginAddress = c("", "15Grand_Ave", "", "700Grand_Ave", 
"", "", "", "2730State_st", "", ""), DestinationAddress = c("", 
"700Grand_Ave", "", "20Washington_Ave", "", "", "", "40Washington_Ave", 
"", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response, Ronak! This is unbelievable! Also, I will vote as soon as I apply these codes to mine. I haven't applied these codes to my dataset yet but I think it will definitely work for my dataset (If not, I will leave a comment here).  Again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Replace empty strings with NA_character: df_clean => data.frame
df_clean <- replace(df, df == "", NA_character_)

# Split apply combine NA filling function per firm: data.frame => stdout (console)
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df_clean, df_clean$Firm), function(x){
  x <- x[order(x$Year),]
  x$Address[1] <- ifelse(is.na(x$Address[1]), 
  x$OriginAddress[which(!(is.na(x$OriginAddress)))[1]],
                         x$Address[1])
  x$Address[which(is.na(x$Address))] <- x$DestinationAddress[which(is.na(x$Address))]
  x$Address <- na.omit(x$Address)[cumsum(!(is.na(x$Address)))]
  return(x)
    }
  )
), row.names = NULL)
```

Using data thanks @Ronak Shah:

```
df <- structure(list(Firm = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B"), Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L), Moveyear = c(NA, 2001L, NA, 2003L, 
NA, NA, NA, 2002L, NA, NA), Address = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), OriginAddress = c("", "15Grand_Ave", "", "700Grand_Ave", 
"", "", "", "2730State_st", "", ""), DestinationAddress = c("", 
"700Grand_Ave", "", "20Washington_Ave", "", "", "", "40Washington_Ave", 
"", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```